# Can't create a windows store package

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am trying to create a store package in visual studio 2013, but when i goStore > Create App Packages > Yes > Next and on page where i should login i can see anything, just white screen. So why i can't log in to Windows Store?

That is what i see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hioRU.png)

I am already tried to clear IE cache and searching this problem do not helping. It is working fine on other computers, but i need it working on mine.
Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstall IE and\or VS. And are you shure, that "Sign in to Windows Store" is an title to login page, and not an appeal to login in it in some another place?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall "**HTTP Debugger**" and "**FastPictureViewer**" will solve the problem .

Answer (score 0):

I had same situation: I just clean all cache/history/cookies in IE and restart IE and VS.

Hope it will help someone.